# substitute for asp.net web form server side controls in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, controls, custom-controls

I am rather new to ASP.NET MVC5. I know server side controls are not working directly in MVC, but there will be some way by which we will get similar controls in MVC5 for rapid development. Can you suggest me how can I find such controls? Can you list out all such mostly used common controls for MVC5?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of a "control" in MVC. There's various things that function similar to Web Form controls, but it depends on what you're trying to do.

1. HTML Helpers are similar in that you essentially call a function that returns rendered HTML. You can extend `HtmlHelper` to add your own.
2. Child actions function as a sort of separate request within the context of the main request. They accept parameters like an action, can do all the backend stuff an action can do (query database, etc.) and return a view rendered based on a model, like a normal view.
3. A partial view, in general, can function as a control as it allows you to insert a snippet of HTML somewhere.
4. Editor templates and display templates can be used in conjunction with `Html.EditorFor` and `Html.DisplayFor`, respectively to render a form field or some sort of HTML display for a particular property on your model.

Comment: what is best way to implement functionality of 1. data grid 2. drop down list 3. date picker control in mvc 5? in general should we use ajax based control or non ajax based controls in mvc5? what is best practice? help me by answering this.

Comment: The first two already exist as HTML helpers. The third requires a JavaScript solution, but you would mostly like utilize an editor template (`Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.cshtml`, for example).

Comment: can you please send me link where I can get 1. data grid 2. drop down list and drop down as html helper class?

Comment: How can we generate reports for asp.net mvc5? does it support SSRS reports? or any other tool is best fitted for report generation in mvc5? what is the best practice?

Comment: please send me link for editor template for datepicker. thanks for your help.

Comment: I meant that they already exist *built-in*. You don't need extra code. As for reporting, I'm not sure what you're looking for. MVC is not for reports. It has nothing to do with SSRS. If you need to display a report from SSRS, you'll need to pull it in as some format that can be used with the web: PDF, HTML, etc.

Comment: in web form we see SSRS is widely used for report in fact people wants pdf reports. Let's say for MVC application having very large data what will be best practice to generate reports? How people are showing reports for large data in the mvc application? How to show pdf report in mvc?

Comment: please send me link where data grid and drop down are builtin as html helper class. also send me link for editor template for datepicker.

Comment: Here's an idea: Read the documentation, write your own code, and stop expecting life to spoon-feed you.